# Is there any way to see the printing message while running Android app?

Tags: android, console

Is there any way to see the printing message `(eg: Log.i('', ''))` while running Android app in Android phone ? (not in emulator).

Comment: I am using Mac OS for Android application development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the log exactly in the same way as you'd view the emulators log. Either using the the Eclipse's ADT logcat view or by issuing `adb logcat` in a terminal.

Comment: I am not able to view the message in ADT logcat.

Comment: You have to activate `USB Debugging` on your device. Go to `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Development` -> check `USB debugging`.

Comment: I done the step, but still I am not able to view the message in logcat.

Comment: Are all necessary device drivers installed? Are from where are you issuing that command? What is the output when you issue that command? I really need more information to help.

Comment: When I tried to reset adb, it shows an alert message. Message: "Adb failed to restart!
Make sure the plugin is properly configured."

Comment: In console, it is printing following message; hierarchyviewer]Unable to debug device HT07LPY04929

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You are supposed to open a terminal window (command line/command prompt) and use `adb` from there or you open the Logcat view in Eclipse.

Comment: if i type adb in terminal, it is showing following message; '-bash: adb: command not found'

Comment: That means you have not added the `skd/tools` and `sdk/platform-tools` directory to your PATH environment variable. Either add it or navigate to the `sdk/platform-tools` directory and try it from there using following syntax `./adb logcat`.

Comment: [Exploring the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents) scroll down to `How to update your PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can debug your application directly on your Android device. You need to enable `USB Debugging` on your device. And whenever you will run/debug that application you will be able to see the messages in `LogCat` view

Comment: How I can enable "USB Debugging" on my device ? Please give me the step.

Answer (score 1):

You can install any logcat application in your phone.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can install [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.juggler.LogcatWidget) after u show your logcat another way

If u r requirement is like u need logcat output withot connecting to PC anyway running in application when u require to download app for that like above